# What is causing "MongoError: no mongos proxy available at Timeout"?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Trying to connect to an Atlas mongodb instance from my Node app running on Google Cloud App Engine and getting the following error:

`MongoError: no mongos proxy available at Timeout`

My connection string is basically this: (have changed some names of shards slightly for obvious reasons)

```
mongodb://
<username>:<password>@
shard-00-00-hfnfz.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,
shard-00-01-hfnfz.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,
shard-00-02-hfnfz.gcp.mongodb.net:27017
/test
?ssl=true
&replicaSet=shard-0
&authSource=admin
```

I can connect fine from my local using Compass. However, when trying to connect via my app running in Google Cloud App Engine, I get the aforementioned error in my logs.

Comment: Tested using mLab and it connects fine. Must be something to do with Atlas. Even though my Atlas mongo instance cloud provider is set to Google Cloud so you would think it would work nicely together.

Comment: This sounds similar to https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3945 , which version of mongoose are you using ?

Comment: i just found this problem also, can someone find the solution?

Comment: @AlongkornChetasumon What are your versions of Mongoose and MongoDB node driver and what Atlas instance type are you trying to connect to? Upgrading to the latest Mongoose version may resolve, but if that doesn't help I would suggest posting a new question with details specific to your environment.

Comment: @Stretch0 could you please also post your `connectionOptions` for Mongoose. I had similar issue and was getting the same error message when I was trying to connect with non sharded MongoDB instance as if it was sharded. The solution was to set `mongos: null` in Mongoose `connectionOptions`. Maybe in your case it also needs to be altered.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? Because I have the same issue.

Comment: No I didn't. I ended up using mlab. @PavelBely did you have any luck resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you've white listed the IP from your server on the Atlas side (from the security tab)

[image]